# Sound playing and forward swiping animation flickering problem in android phonegap and jqtouch?

Tags: android, jqtouch, cordova

I am developing an app using phonegap for android. It consists of around 25 images and similar number of mp3 files. Each mp3 file has duration not more than 10 seconds. The requirement of app is whenever a image is shown on screen its related mp3 file should be played. I am using jqtouch swipe action to move from one page to another. I am facing following problems both on emulator and real device(samsung galaxy 3)-

1. After 15-20 images sound stops playing both on emulator and galaxy 3. In logcat I got following error

   ERROR/AudioFlinger(34): not enough memory for AudioTrack size=49216

I am using following code to play mp3 files

```
if(mp3file!=null){
            mp3file.stop();

            mp3file = null;
        }

        mp3file = new Media("/android_asset/www/name_of_file.mp3",
            function() {
                console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
            },
                function(err) {

            },
                function(status) {
                               });
          mp3file.play();
```

I think error is due to audiomanager objects from phonegap api of each mp3 file remaining in memory. 
 I want to know how to destroy media object created in javascript. You can play, stop, pause. But is there any method in phonegap for android to destroy it so that it does not remain in memory after it has done playing.

1. Another problem that I am facing is related with left swipe action in jqtouch to view next image. If I am currently viewing image1 and if I try to view image2 by left swipe action, image2 is shown for short amount of time and after that image1 is shown for a moment and after that again image2 is shown. In short the transition from image1 to
   image2 is not smooth and it has flickering effects. However if i go from image2 to image1 using right swipe transition is smooth.

Thanks

Comment: you could play the song with the HTML5 Audio Tag if you believe there is an error in the PhoneGap code

Answer (score 0):

I got some help with another developer on this.The trick is to make a function declare mp3file outside the function then call stopRecord() on it.(even though you're not doing recording).I tested this with a simple button playing the sound over and over and it worked 75 times before I got tired of playing with it.

Let me know it works for you.

```
var mp3file;
function playAudio(){


if(mp3file!=null){
            mp3file.stop();
            mp3file.stopRecord();
            mp3file=null;

        }

       mp3file = new Media("/android_asset/www/yourmp3.mp3",
            function() {
                console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
            },
                function(err) {

            },
                function(status) {
                               });
          mp3file.play();



}
```